# Create variations of data efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

I have 4 parameters. I need to create a new table that holds all possible variations of these 4 parameters divided by themself.
this is an example of 4 parameters:
the original parameters:

```
 p1  | p2  |  p3 |  p4 |  
=====+=====+=====+=====+
  8  |  8  |  8  |  8  |
```

The new table should contain:

```
 p1  | p2  |  p3 |  p4 |  
=====+=====+=====+=====+
  8  |  8  |  8  |  8  | The original raw  
  1  |  8  |  8  |  8  | One cell devided by 8 (4 rows overall)  
  8  |  1  |  8  |  8  |    
  8  |  8  |  1  |  8  |    
  8  |  8  |  8  |  1  |
  1  |  1  |  8  |  8  | Two cells divided by 8 (6 rows overall)  
  1  |  8  |  1  |  8  |    
  1  |  8  |  8  |  1  |    
  8  |  1  |  1  |  8  |    
  8  |  1  |  8  |  1  |           
  8  |  8  |  1  |  1  |           
  1  |  1  |  1  |  8  | Three cells divided by 8 (4 rows overall) 
  1  |  1  |  8  |  1  |    
  1  |  8  |  1  |  1  |    
  8  |  1  |  1  |  1  |    
  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  | All cells divided by 8 (1 row overall)
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it, because the next level might be to do the same but with 5 parameters (and do all kinds of mathematical operations).
I thought to use a WHILE loop, but I don't know how can I "run" on the columns like a *nested for loop* in c/c++/java/python etc.   Are there other ways to create this? What is the efficient way to do it?

Comment: Efficient is to use set based operations, for example cross join to itself. Are your parameters always equal?

Comment: No, the parameters are not equal. I used simple parameters only for the explanation. @Arvo

Comment: Next time you should maybe present a bit more complex example - from your example I could create binary solution - your 8-s and 1-s follow nicely "display all 4-bit binary numbers" pattern :)

Comment: can you please show your solution for that? that's an interesting idea for that problem :) I'm at the begging of SQL, so ideas are welcome. @Arvo

Comment: No time for solutions currently, sorry :( Ideas are more important anyway :)

Comment: Are the parameters rows in a table?  What do you mean "divided by 8"?  What if the values are different?

Comment: Yes, the parameters rows in a table and the values are different. I used these numbers for a simple example. Each parameter holds a different number, but the mathematical operation is the same. For example, the parameters can be: 100, 0.2, -6, 18  and the operation: multiply by 5. so in this case, we will get: the first row is the original one. Second row: 20, 0.2, -6, 18. Third row: 100, 0.1, -6,18. Fourth row: 100, 0.2, -3, 18 etc. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

The `cross join` solution:

```
select *
from
    (values (8),(1)) as q1(p1)
    cross join
    (values (8),(1)) as q2(p2)
    cross join
    (values (8),(1)) as q3(p3)
    cross join
    (values (8),(1)) as q4(p4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you can use `apply`:

```
select p1.p1, p2.p2, p3.p3, p4.p4
from t cross apply
     (values (t.p1, t.p1 / 8.0)) p1(p1) cross apply
     (values (t.p2, t.p2 / 8.0)) p2(p2) cross apply
     (values (t.p3, t.p3 / 8.0)) p3(p3) cross apply
     (values (t.p4, t.p4 / 8.0)) p4(p4) ;
```

Note:  A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns.  If you need to handle a variable number of parameters, then you need dynamic SQL.

That said, it should be obvious how to handle whatever specific number of parameters you need to.